# C# AutoSize Label Issue

Tags: c#, autosize

In my program I have label controls which users can add at will, the labels can be bound to data source too.  I added the AutoSize property to a property grid I designed and there is the option to turn this on and off at will.  The problem I am running into is that if the AutoSize flag is set to true in the property grid it will AutoSize to the current cell contents which is correct but if I move ahead one record in my data source and the text is longer then the label the label will not resize again.  Am I doing something wrong or this the way AutoSize works?

Also does anyone know if it possible to make snap lines available at run time to align controls?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if I'm understanding your question correctly you're creating a custom component "label" and the problem is that is doesn't adjust its size when its text is changed. Take a look at the [Control.OnTextChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.ontextchanged.aspx) method, you can put your size adjusting logic there. Smth like this:

```
public class TestLabel : Control
{
  protected override void OnTextChanged(EventArgs e)
  {
   // adjust size here
   base.OnTextChanged(e);
  }
}
```

as for snap lines, those are drown by designer, in run time you can draw them yourself by overriding your form or parent control OnPaint method